# How to let username to decide which mysql database it has to access during php login?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have different database for different client for some client i had given same database.
i want username to decide which database it has access.How to do that?

> Usernames: john102, jack103, rita104 access DB1
>
> *Clients having username that contain number 100 to 200 access db1*
>
> Username: mark204, lober209, monica306 etc access db2
>
> *Clients - username contain numbers 200 to 500 access db2*

Please help with an example.

will this make my system any faster? Or shall I use 1 database for all users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this code at the top of your file.

```
mysql_connect('host','username','password');

    $str = 'john204'; //This is your username 
    $no = substr($str,-3);

    if($no >= 100 && $no < 200)
    {
        mysql_select_db("db1");

        // echo 'we are selecting db1';
    }
    else if($no >= 200 && $no < 500)
    {
        mysql_select_db("db2");

        // echo 'we are selecting db2';
    }
```

If you still need help feel free to comment.